Downloading PDF using Selenium and Python in Chrome: Disabling PDF Viewer
What I see currentlyI am trying to download a pdf after clicking on the button to do so but by default Chrome will use PDF Viewer. I have implemented the following code, which seems to stop the viewer from showing the PDF itself, but the frame of the viewer remains and a button exists in order to download. I am stuck because this button element does not show in the page source for Selenium to read. So I either need a solution to read this additional element or implement a better solution to disabling the PDF viewer completely.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "file_path", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, 
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome 
})
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

enter image description here
I have tried this code. I need suggestions to fix. thank you

You can try:

Set the option plugins.always_open_pdf_externally to False.
Add an option named profile.default_content_settings.popups with a
value 0.

The whole option is:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,  # disable the popup window
"download.default_directory": "file_path", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, 
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": False #It will not show PDF directly in chrome 
})
wd = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


Thank you for your response but now the entire PDF Viewer is showing as if I implemented no code. @

@AustinSimpson Can you post the url of the pdf file?

Originally no. I did not think I had access to it, but after further digging into the html I was able to find the src link within the embedded Iframe. Now I am able to use driver.get(src) and it is downloaded instantly. Thank you for your help!
